# Transliteration API for .net

Tags: asp.net, transliteration

I am developing an intranet application using ASP.Net. The application will not have access to internet.

In this application, I need to transliterate proper nouns (name of persons) to one or more Indian scripts. As application does not have access to internet, using Google/Microsoft transliteration API is not an option.

I am told that transliteration functionality of Google Input Tool (http://www.google.com/inputtools/windows/) with appropriate language packs can be accessed programmatically - but a) I haven't come across any example and b) is it legally permitted?

I also checked http://www.vishalon.net/PramukhIME/JavaScriptLibrary.aspx, but in that the transliteration quality needs a bit of improvement.

Are there any other offline options available for using is this scenario.

Thanks.

Vikram

Comment: Did you find a working solution? Did you try the Microsoft MTU (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688104.aspx) that supports Iniktikut/Malayalam<>Romanization directions? Do you really mean transliteration or font/encoding conversion?

Comment: I did mean transliteration. Similar to what is available at https://translate.google.co.in/.  No, I haven't found any solution for this as yet. I had to defer this feature in our application for a later release.

Comment: So, you are trying to leverage machine translation, not pure transliteration. You will hardly find such an offline solution. Moses does not seem to support Hindi as per this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669446/statistical-machine-translation-from-hindi-to-english-using-moses. You could try some luck with Apertium (http://sourceforge.net/projects/apertium), but from all Indian languages it only supports Hindi. Anusaaraka could possibly help (http://anusaaraka.iiit.ac.in/node/40), but it is still under development. Offline Google Translate is only available for mobiles. :(